# Inequality for Gaussian polynomials III

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, polynomials, inequalities

Recall the constructions $[n]_q=\frac{1-q^n}{1-q}, [n]!_q=[1]_q[2]_q\cdots[n]_q$ with $[0]!_q:=1$ and the $q$-binomials (Gaussian polynomials)
$$\binom{n}k_q=\frac{[n]!_q}{[k]!_q[n-k]!_q}.$$
Given two polynomials $f(q)$ and $g(q)$, we write $f(q)\geq g(q)$ provided that $f(q)-g(q)$ is a polynomial having non-negative coefficients.

I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Suppose $0\leq k\leq a<b$ are integers.
> Is it true that $\binom{b+a}{b-k}_q\geq\binom{a+b}{a-k}_q$?

Comment: There is a closely related question on unimodality discussed here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.7087.pdf
The cool thing is that a similar difference gets an interpretation from representation theory, in terms of Kronecker coefficients.

Answer (score 6):

We know that there is a $q$-unimodality of the $q$-binomial coefficients. That is, $\binom{n}{k}_q - \binom{n}{k-1}_q$ has nonnegative coefficients for $k \leq n/2$. This was shown by Lynne M. Butler in [A unimodality result in the enumeration of subgroups of a finite abelian group](https://doi.org/10.2307/2046687) (in more generality than just $q$-binomials).

Now we just observe that $b-k$ is closer to the center peak at $(a+b)/2$ then $a-k$ is. So, $\binom{b+a}{b-k}_q - \binom{a+b}{a-k}$ has nonnegative coefficients as desired.

Comment: A paper by G.E.Andrews, On the difference of successive Gaussian polynomials, J. Statistical Planning and Inference, 1993 gives a combinatorial proof regrading $\binom{n}k_q-\binom{n}{k-1}_q\geq0$. The last line in your argument seems to require more justification (although it is plausible, in principle).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an alternating approach to that of Butler and Andrews, let's show that $\binom{n}k_q-\binom{n}{k-1}_q\geq0$, provided $2k\leq n$.

Let $n=\alpha k+d$ where $0\leq d<k$. Rewrite
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}k_q-\binom{n}{k-1}_q
&=q^k\binom{n}{k-1}_q\frac{1-q^{(\alpha-2)k}}{1-q^k}
+q^{(\alpha-1)k}\binom{n}{k-1}_q\frac{1-q^{d+1}}{1-q^k}.
\end{align*}
Observe $\frac{1-q^{(\alpha-2)k}}{1-q^k}$ is already a polynomial with non-negative coefficients. Furthermore, since $U(q):=\binom{n}{k-1}_q$ is unimodal, the coefficient of $q^j$ in $U(q)\cdot(1-q^{d+1})$ is non-negative as long as $2j\leq\deg(U)$. The same is true for $U(q)\frac{1-q^{d+1}}{1-q^k}$ as a formal power series. Since the *polynomial* $U(q)\frac{1-q^{d+1}}{1-q^k}$ is *symmetric*, having degree no greater than $U(q)$, all remaining coefficients of $U(q)\frac{1-q^{d+1}}{1-q^k}$ are non-negative.